# Fullscreen state with Youtube Iframe API on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube

I'm trying to find a way of knowing when a Youtube video on an iPhone enters/exists fullscreen inside an HTML page. I am using Safari Mobile, not a UIWebView, the videos automatically go fullscreen as soon as they start playing.

Being obviously not on the youtube.com domain I cannot bind the **webkitbeginfullscreen** and **webkitbendfullscreen** on the <video> element within the iframe.

Is there any technique, even hacks, allowing me to query the video fullscreen state?

Comment: Added a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6673), we'll see what Youtube has to say about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to detect `iPhone` or `iPod` user agent and then if the time changed on the video (via YouTube Javascript API) then you would have to assume it was playing.

Although, that only gets you equivalent `beginfullscreen` event reliably.